# Compositor for RHEL7?

Tags: linux, rhel, window-manager, xmonad

I have Xmonad window manager installed on a RHEL 7.9 machine. The issue is I cannot seem to set the transparency for my terminal windows.

From the little previous experience I have with this, I believe I need some form of compositor.

I have tried doing a yum search for the usual suspects of compton/picom but cannot seem to find them. (This is a work machine and so I believe it has a subset of the main package repos available).

Is there any compositor like this which I should be able to use? Has anyone done this on RHEL?

If the answer is there are packages available, and I just cannot see them, I am able to request for packages to be added to our repository too, I simply need to know what they are.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! Welcome here. "Compositor" in the context of X11 means "compositing window manager". Your window manager is Xmonad. Either it supports transparent windows (which basically means it supports AIGLX), or it does not; it's a fundamental architectural thing for a window manager. I don't know Xmonad well enough to know whether it does.

Comment: I've used xmonad before on unbuntu and arch. Both times the transparency worked fine but I first had to install either 'compton or picom'. I thought it would be a similar process here for RHEL, however I cannot find either package availabe, or an alternative

Comment: Ah! You know more than I do! You have more experience than your question claims :) I don't know from the top of my head whether those are in there, but I'll assume you have the EPEL repos enabled, right?

Comment: Sort of. We have a limited subset available which I believe the IT department manage. As suggested by @MC68020 below, I was able to request xcompmgr to be installed, added that to the 'xstartup' file under ~/.vnc/ and everything is working now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that Xmonad will limit the list of possible choices.

However, Xmonad has the ability to use some compositing features such as transparency **when used with a composite aware app (1)** and [xcompmgr](https://github.com/freedesktop/xcompmgr).

> xcompmgr is a sample compositing manager for X servers supporting the
> XFIXES, DAMAGE, RENDER, and COMPOSITE extensions.  It enables basic
> eye-candy effects.

**1/ Enable compositing in your X server** configuration by enabling the *Composite* option in your `xorg.conf` file (or any file sitting in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`)

```
Section "Extensions"
     Option "Composite" "enable"
EndSection
```

restart the X server and confirm it's working :

```
xdpyinfo | grep Composite
```

**2/ Start the compositor**

```
xcompmgr -c &
```

You may want to add this line into your `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession`
You might also want adding other options, see [some manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/xcompmgr-1.html).

---

***1 :** Since you mention terminal applications, some might not be composite aware.
[urxwt](https://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt) is. If using it then you might need to adjust some dedicated settings as part of your `~/.Xdefaults` (see the manpage linked above)

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I still cannot get it working though. I do not seem to have xcompmgr available. Do you mean to install this manually or should it be available on RHEL already?

As this is a work machine I cannot install anything directly from github, it would need to be available through the yum package manager.

I probably should also mention I'm connected through vnc. I have added the xcompmgr -c line to my xstartup file under ~/.vnc. Is this correct?

Comment: @D.Sill : I cannot tell regarding RHEL repo. However the package is indeed available in Fedora-EPEL (  https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/xcompmgr ) It should then consequently be available for RHEL systems.

Comment: Marking this as the solution. I was able to get xcompmgr installed (had to request it through IT services as our company only gives us a subset of EPEL packages to install). Started it inside ~/.vnc/xstartup after starting xmonad and now it is all working as expected. Thanks for your help.